# Tkinter button can only be clicked once

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a Python Tkinter program which accepts some user inputs (mostly checkbuttons) then when the user clicks the 'START' button it runs some code to copy certain files (based on which checkbuttons are clicked) to a folder on the desktop.

The program is working fine, but after I click Start and it runs, I cannot click start again (say if i want to click another checkbutton to copy a different file).  I'm not sure what the issue is but hoping someone can help me.  I am not going to paste all of the code because it is about 1500 lines due to the man if elif statements and checkbutton declarations.  If needed I can post it to pastebin or something similar.  I will post what I think are the relevant parts but feel free to let me know if you need other snippets.

Thanks in advance for any tips to get this to work more in the way I intend it.

```
validLocation = False
validUser = None
validPassword = None

destination = r'C:\Users\Jordan.Hawkes\Desktop\Copied_Files'

def start():
    if validLocation == False or validUser == False or validPassword == False:
        get_user()
        if validUser == True and validPassword == True:
            get_location()
            if validLocation == True:
                if not os.path.exists(destination):
                    os.makedirs(destination)
                get_programs()
                errorLabel.configure(text="Starting File Copy", fg='green')
            else:
                if not validLocation:
                    errorLabel.configure(text="Missing Parameter:\n You MUST select a location.")
                elif not validType:
                    errorLabel.configure(text="Missing Parameter:\n You MUST select an Installation Type.")
```

get_user(), get_location(), get_version() just help to validate inputs from the user before copying the files.  I do not believe the are relevant here so I will leave them out.

```
buttonFrame = Frame(contentFrame, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
buttonFrame.pack(fill=X)

startButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='START', width=25, command=start, bg='green')
startButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
quitButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='QUIT', width=25, command=quit, bg='red')
quitButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Thanks for the help.  The following code was able to fix the issue:

```
def start():
    global validLocation, validUser, validPassword
    if validLocation == False or validUser == False or validPassword == False:
        get_user()
        if validUser == True and validPassword == True:
            get_location()
            if validLocation == True:
                if not os.path.exists(destination):
                    os.makedirs(destination)
                get_programs()
                errorLabel.configure(text="Starting File Copy", fg='green')
                validLocation = False;
                validUser = None;
                validPassword = None;
            else:
                if not validLocation:
                    errorLabel.configure(text="Missing Parameter:\n You MUST select a location.")
                elif not validType:
                    errorLabel.configure(text="Missing Parameter:\n You MUST select an Installation Type.")
```

Comment: What does _" I cannot click start again "_ - why can't you click it? Does it disappear? Is it disabled?

Comment: No it doesn't disappear and it seems to be enabled? Just when I click it nothing happens, like it doesn't start the start() function again which I was hoping it would

Comment: @JordanHawkes If you are done, reset all these variable to `False`: `if validLocation == False or validUser == False or validPassword == False:`

Comment: Oh, so you _can_ click it, but it appears nothing happens. What have you done to debug this?  Have you tried putting a `print` statement at the very top of the `start` function to verify it's being called? Have you verified that all of the variables used in the conditional statement are what you're assuming they are?

Comment: so the variables are good at the beginning of the program.  After running once they all stay as True True even when I put in this code to reset each variable...     
    validLocation == FALSE
    validUser == NONE
    validPassword == NONE

Comment: @JordanHawkes: Should be read: `validLocation = False ; validUser = None ; validPassword = None` and you are using `globals` read [scopes-and-namespaces-example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: Thanks, wrong syntax.  I imported global at the beginning and now it runs fine! Figured I was missing something dumb. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's now working.  Thanks for your help.  I edited the question with the solution!